# MS SQL query converted to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to find all employees whose review is due in the next 45 days. I have the MS SQL:

```
Select * 
from Employee 
where DATEDIFF(yy,HireDate,GetDate()+45) > DATEDIFF(yy,HireDate,GetDate())
```

How does this convert to MySQL?

Comment: Did you try to convert this to MySQL?  Please edit your question with your conversion attempts.

Comment: MySQL's `DATEDIFF` is a bit different.  Also, to get the current time in MySQL, it's `NOW()` or `CURDATE()`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: actually CurDate is more correct as he's not looking for a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Select * 
from Employee 
where DATEDIFF(HireDate,DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 45 DAY)) > DATEDIFF(HireDate,CURDATE())
```

Comment: This is more correct than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use CurDate instead of GetDate, so it'd just be:

```
Select * from Employee where DATEDIFF(HireDate,CurDate()) > DATEDIFF(HireDate,CurDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to check `DATEDIFF` once.  Just get the number of days and compare.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), HireDate) <= 45
```

Docs for MySQL's `DATEDIFF` (and other date/time functions): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html